# Workbook.Activate method

Tags: excel, vba

i got a variable:

```
V_WBNameOutPut as string
```

and use it inside the following code:

```
Application.Workbooks(V_WBNameOutPut).Activate
```

This two part of code are inside a huger code which work fine for 99.99% of different users, but only for one user the code go in error and when I debug its stop to  Application.Workbooks(V_WBNameOutPut).Activate line.
And the error is the following:

Runtime Error 9: Subscript Out of Range

Any ideas why this happend and possible solution?

Thanks

I try it to debug but the code works fine but for one particular user it doesn't

```
The subroutine to generate the output file, which the Application.Workbooks(V_WBNameOutPut).Activate refers to:

    Sub CreateWB()
    Dim File_Name           As Variant
    Dim File_Name_Saved     As String
    Dim i_attempt           As Integer
    Dim NewWorkBook         As Workbook
     Set NewWorkBook = Workbooks.Add
     Do While i_attempt < 2
         i_attempt = i_attempt + 1     
        File_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=V_WBNameOutPut, filefilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx),*.xlsx,Excel-Macro Files (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", Title:="Please choose a Folder")
        File_Name_Saved = Left(Right(File_Name, Len(V_WBNameOutPut) + 5), Len(V_WBNameOutPut))
         If File_Name = False Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            End
        Else
            If UCase(File_Name_Saved) <> UCase(V_WBNameOutPut) Then
                If i_attempt < 2 Then
                    MsgBox "Please do not change the File name" & vbCrLf & i_attempt & "/2 Attempt"
                Else
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close
                    End
                End If
            Else
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                NewWorkBook.SaveAs File_Name, ConflictResolution:=True
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: When this happens: have you checked the content of `V_Outputname` and if the according Workbook is open?

Comment: I find that if in `File Explorer` I have ticked _File name extensions_ then `Book1.xlsx` works, but `Book1` throws the out of range error.  If I don't have _File name extensions_ ticked then both work.  The state of the tick box affects what appears in the Excel title bar (might have to close and reopen the file).

Comment: V_WBNameOutPut is populated correctly, my doubt is now that , the file is not generated with that name as I use another subroutine to create the output file first, and after I call the output file to paste some value

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the open workbooks looking for a match without the file extension. A better solution would be to make CreateWB a function that returns the saved filename.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim V_WBNameOutPut

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    V_WBNameOutPut = "test2"
    
    CreateWB
    For Each wb In Workbooks
       If wb.Name Like V_WBNameOutPut & "*" Then
            wb.Activate
            Exit For
       End If
    Next
    Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Select ' active workbook
  
End Sub

Sub CreateWB()

    Dim NewWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim fso As Object, bSaveOK As Boolean, i_attempt As Integer
    Dim File_Name As Variant, File_Name_Saved As String
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For i_attempt = 1 To 2
        File_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
            InitialFileName:=V_WBNameOutPut, _
            filefilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx),*.xlsx,Excel-Macro Files (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", _
            Title:="Please choose a Folder")
            
        If File_Name = False Then Exit Sub
        
        bSaveOK = (fso.getbasename(File_Name) = V_WBNameOutPut)
        If Not bSaveOK And i_attempt = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Please do not change the File name from " & V_WBNameOutPut _
            & vbCrLf & i_attempt & "/2 Attempt"
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    ' create workbook and save
    If bSaveOK Then
        Set NewWorkBook = Workbooks.Add
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        NewWorkBook.SaveAs File_Name, ConflictResolution:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is with the Application.Workbooks(V_WBNameOutPut).Activate, when I change the V_WBNameOutPut  from FileName_Example in V_WBNameOutPu =  FileName_Example.xlsx it works.